# import/require bootstrap in JavaScript file within Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, import, bootstrap-5

we have a custom built JavaScript file which is injected as a script file in index.html into Consumer application having bootstrap 5 version installed using npm in the package.json of an angular application.

we also have bootstrap popover control initialization in our custom JavaScript file.

we are facing issues when trying to use the bootstrap 5 version dependency injected in the angular application in our custom JavaScript file.

It is throwing a console error saying `bootstrap is not defined`.
I have also tried importing the bootstrap using this syntax `import 'bootstrap';`, even this is throwing error.
I have also tried referencing the manual files in angular.json using below code, even that didn't work.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

Can anyone suggest me the right way of consuming the bootstrap referenced in the angular project to my custom developed JavaScript file?

Comment: This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-bootstrap?file=angular.json) gives one option via `angular.json`. Alternatively using [styles.css](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-include?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: Importing all of bootstrap css/js is not really sustainable. Importing bootstrap.scss increases your main bundle size with 160 kB, which is 30% of the pre-configured warning-main-bundle-size. Bundling all the bootstrap js along would be absolute overkill. It's recommended to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/), or for the hypermilers [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) which splits up both the js and css

Comment: As a note: don't forget to generate one module per page, using the following command: `ng g module register --module account --route register`. Only import the modules you actually need for that specific page